# Is there a way to change "home" directory in Intellij?

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, ide, relative-path

I'm using intellij Idea, and new to linux
So for example, I have a project directory structure below

```
ProjectFolder  
|--> src  
| | |--> MyCodes.java  
| | |--> hello.txt
```

Now, if I want to access hello.txt in MyCodes.java with relative path, I need to use "src/hello.txt", where the "home" directory is the ProjectFolder. However, if I copy my files in src(without src folder) into linux, it would fail to run. Is there a way I can set src as "home", so I can access with relative path simply "hello.txt", and therefore won't fail even after copying to linux?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set the **Working directory** in the Run configuration:

[image: working directory]